# How to have a function run while taking from a segmented controller and textfields

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a single view app that could simply calculate what you would need on a final depending on numerical values in two text fields (Current grade and percentage weight of the final) and a segmented controller with A, B, C, and D. I'm lost though on how to make a function that will change a label whenever it detects a change in either the segmented controller or the text fields.

On the most recent version of Xcode

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gradeCurrent: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var finalWeight: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var gradeWanted: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var gradeNeeded: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I want the ending label to have added on a rounded up number of what is required to achieve the grade

Comment: for Textfield go through this tutorial.. https://grokswift.com/uitextfield/ . for SegmentController try this tutorial. https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/segmented-control-ios-tutorial

Comment: Break the problem down to its parts. Do you know how to handle a text field changing? Do you know how to handle a segment changing? Tackle each of those first. Once you can do that, look into how to have each of those cause the label to be updated.